Model Loader errors in Text Gen Web UI`
I have tried loading multiple models from HuggingFace using Text Gen Web UI, but no matter the model or the loader, I get the same "ModuleNotFoundError" for the loaders.
Importantly, I am using an Intel i7 and not a GPU, but I have been able to run smaller models using different UI tools in the past.
Steps I followed:

Cloned Text Gen from Git Created a new environment in Anaconda.Navigator.
Using Visual Studio Code opened Text Generation Web UI.
I selected the environment's Python as the Python interpreter.
Selected to activate the relevant conda environment and installed the requirements.txt file for Text Generation Web UI.
Started the application using the one_click.py file that comes with Text Generation Web UI.

Upon failing to get a model to load, I tried many things:

Re-installing pip packages.
Installing a different version of torch: pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
Deleting the environment and starting over.
Asking ChatGPT and CoPilot a million questions.

The same errors appear over and over. It is driving me crazy!
Examples (each of these have been installed, in the correct environment):

ModuleNotFoundError: Failed to import 'autogptq'. Please install it
manually following the instructions in the AutoGPTQ GitHub repository.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exllamav2'
OSError: Error no file named pytorch_model.bin, model.safetensors,
tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.index or flax_model.msgpack found in directory
models\meta-llama_Llama-3.2-1B.


The issue here is that for some reason, that's never really explained, even if you have python installed correctly, with all of the dependencies required... the webui will still use it's own embedded version of python and ignore what you've got installed. So you can troubleshoot and install until you're blue in the face and it won't change a thing. Ask me how I know and why I'm annoyed with their setup right now... The easiest fix is to just do the setup yourself.
Download Anaconda
open "anaconda prompt" (not cmd)
conda create --name textgen python=3.10
conda activate textgen
cd C:\path\to\text-generation-webui
pip install auto-gptq
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt

from then on when you want to start the server. start anaconda, move to the webui folder and use
conda activate textgen
python server.py

Hopefully I didn't butcher any of those commands but this should be enough to hopefully get you over the hurdle.
please note that these steps were completed after the initial install of the webui.
